# Connect Four Java Game Project, need help on basic concepts

Tags: java, class, user-interface, arraylist, connect

I am working on a lab, it's a connect four game. I'm having trouble specifically with basic concepts like how classes communicate with each other, how to use private instance variables, how to use an ArrayList, how to compare JLabels or set them as something comparable...

To give a brief breakdown I have four classes GUI, Game, Player, Name

I can create the GUI by using two four loops, the game is a grid with 7 columns of 6 pieces. The pieces are images,

```
JLabel Piece = new JLabel("images/blank.png");
```

for example to denote an empty spot.

The GUI is based on a JFrame, single content pane and four panels, one for a header which indicates who is playing and who won, another for the 7 buttons accompanying the 7 rows, the grid itself of the possible places to be played and then a button panel which gives you the option to replay.

I'm lacking in a lot of concepts. For instance, the replay button shouldn't appear until the game has ended.

I don't understand how to use an ArrayList. I tried to use

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<JLabel>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<JLabel>>();
```

So when I create the GUI by running two for loops like so

```
For ( c = 0 ; c<8 ; c++) {
ArrayList<JLabel> column = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
For ( r = 0 ; r<7 ; r++) {
ArrayList<JLabel> row = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
JLabel empty = new JLabel("images/blank.png");
row.add(empty);
}
column.add(row);
}
```

Even this small step I've already got confused. 
I know the two for loops above are not correct specifically the ArrayList. 
I don't know how to create the arraylist and then use them.

using something like

```
column.get().get();
myList.get().get();
```

to get a specific piece.

I don't know how to pass that to an argument so that for example if I push on button 7 for column 7, and no pieces have been played yet, I can start from the lowest area column 7 row 6 and update that to a played piece, red or yellow for the appropriate player.

This is vague and I doubt I'll get anywhere but I am desperate for help. There isn't much time available from the TA's / Teacher and I believe I am lacking significantly to be able to finish this project.

I understand how it works/what I have to do in words but in terms of applying Java code... 
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to talk to your TAs/Professors. They are likely a better resource for learning Java basics than we are. Another good place to look for information on specific classes is the [online API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: Can you summarize your problem in single line?

Comment: Read my article [2048 Game in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=516) to see how a Swing application is put together and how classes communicate with each other.

Comment: haha funny to see where you started (me)

Answer (score 2):

OK first off you should use an array of Enums.  ArrayLists are intended for lots of items and that can have rapidly changing numbers.  Arrays are intended to house data in a grid of some sorts.  Since you are using a static board, use arrays!  They are also much less memory-intensive.  Example:

```
//Note you should use [column][row] as that is common practice.
States[][] grid = new States[7][6];
//And initialize it:
for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
    for(int o = 0; o < grid[i].length; o++)
        grid[i][o] = EMPTY_JLABEL;
```

Then declare an enum (this is a new class)  (NOTE: replace FULL_PLAYER_ONE_JLABEL and FULL_PLAYER_TWO_JLABEL with the JLabels that have the image for each.):

```
public enum States {
    FULL_PLAYER_ONE(FULL_PLAYER_ONE_JLABEL), FULL_PLAYER_TWO(FULL_PLAYER_TWO_JLABEL), EMPTY(EMPTY_JLABEL);

    //The image of the appropriate state.
    private JLabel label;

    //Enum constructors must be private
    private States(JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public JLabel getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

In your GUI, have a JButton that is only added to the frame when the game is over.  Also add a button to indicate when each column has been clicked by the player.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
//Initialize JButton and add to frame...

//Anytime before the frame is set to visible:
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* Perform tests for for what should happen.
           For example test whose turn it is then call a method to add a piece to that column.  Then call a checker to see if someone has won.  If so, display the replay button, otherwise do nothing (allow other player to move).
        */
    }
}
```